# Redirect to index.php of requested subfolder

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect to `index.php` of whichever directory is requested.

So I need:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/files/hello.php
```

To Redirect to:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/files/index.php
```

And also same for any subfolders:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/files/pages/other/hello.php
```

Redirect to:

```
http://www.site.com/folder/files/pages/other/index.php
```

Answer (score 7):

#### The (technically) right way

Construct a URI consisting of the current scheme (`http` / `https` / etc), hostname and path of the current file and issue a *Location* header.

```
$url = sprintf('%s://%s%s/index.php',
    $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 80 ? 'http' : 'https',
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/'))
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

This is because a location header URI should be complete and absolute. Relative URIs are technically not allowed however there is a draft specification set to change this.

#### The pragmatic way

Just issue a relative *Location* header as it will most probably work.

```
header('Location: index.php');
exit;
```

Comment: For all PHP code above, surround with: '<?php' and '?>', and make sure the file ends with .php so it will be parsed by the PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in .htaccess itself so no need of any PHP code.

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your  `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule (.+?)/[^./]+\.php$ /$1/index.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect `folder/files/hello.php` to `folder/files/index.php` use the following lines in your `folder/files/hello.php` file.

```
<?php

$URL =  'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/folder/files/index.php';

header("Location:  $URL ");

?>
```

use similar syntax for next redirection.